# set kendo drop down span id

Tags: kendo-ui, html-select

i want to set diff. id of kendo drop down parent `<span>`
here is simple code of two d-d

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
            <input id="dropdownlist" />
            <input id="newdropdownlist" />
            <script>
                $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
                  dataSource: [
                    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
                  ],
                  dataTextField: "name",
                  dataValueField: "id",
                  index: 1
                });

                $("#newdropdownlist1").kendoDropDownList({
                  dataSource: [
                    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
                  ],
                  dataTextField: "name",
                  dataValueField: "id",
                  index: 1
                });
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

how can set different id of both drop down span help me out this.
thanks.

Comment: What span element ? Do you talk about the span generated by the DropDownList? Why would you need to change its ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.closest()` function to move up the DOM tree and find a parent.

```
$("#newdropdownlist1") // target the original input element
    .closest(".k-dropdown") // move up the DOM to the dropdown span
    .attr("id", "theNewId"); // change the id attribute
```